# Trying to retrieve an object's color from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, colors, p5.js

So I've been at this for hours and my brain is fried so I could use a bit of assistance.

I need to take the color value from the most recently added object in an array and use it for a separate function.

In the comments it's objective #4. I haven't been able to get the syntax right and so far google has been completely useless.

```
function mousePressed() {
saveSpot();
print(spots);
}

function saveSpot() {
  let newSpot = new Spot (mouseX, mouseY, currentColor());
  spots.push(newSpot);
}

function lastColor() {
 var lastColor = color(255);

 // #4 Return the color of the most recently added Spot in the spots array

return lastColor;
}

function drawLastColor() {
  fill(lastColor());
  textSize(50);
  text("L", 10, 50);
}

function currentColor() {
  return color(0, mouseX, mouseY);
}

class Spot {
  constructor(x, y, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.color = color;
    this.size = 25;
  }

  draw() {
    noStroke();
    fill(this.color);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
  }
}
```

If you need to see more of the code or need any more info just ask and I'll provide what I can. Any help you guys could give would be greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You could take the last element of `spots` and take the `color` property.

```
function lastColor() {
    return spots[spots.length - 1].color;
}
```

With check if the last element exists. If not `undefined` is returned.

```
function lastColor() {
    var last = spots[spots.length - 1];
    return last && last.color;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to take last element added to the array, it's gonna be `spots.pop()`
Since you have a Spot object there, try with `spots.pop().color`.

Be aware, since `pop` modifies the array in place. If you need to lookup the value, try with `spots[spots.length-1].color`